# Dropdown list with limited range of choices in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to bind a field in a View to a property in a ViewModel. The object is "Program" and has the properties "Name" and "Level". So the user should be able to set the name of a program and the level of experience he/she has with this program.

Program is a table in an Sql Server database, and is accessed through Entity Framework. So it would be easy enough to bind the Level property in the ViewModel to a textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Level)
```

But I want a dropdownlist with a limited number of levels (1-5). So how do I do this and still have the dropdownlist bind to the ViewModel property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Level, new SelectList(new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) );
```